# Convert Long Lat wrong location when displaying

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have a long lat I don't know if it is in decimal or in degrees format. So I would like to ask if what in my two computation is correct or if it both wrong. I tried both computation and shows both wrong location so I guess that there's something I'm missing.

Here's the raw long lat which I can't figure out if it is in degrees or decimal.

LAT  = 1430.4903N
LONG = 12059.8999E

My first computation would be like

```
LAT  = 1430.4903 / 100 =  14.304903
LONG = 12059.8999 /100 =  120.598999
```

while my seconds computation would be like

```
Degrees: 14         = 14
Minutes: 30 /60     = 0.5
Seconds : 49/3600   = 0.013611

Degrees + minutes + seconds = 14.513611

Degrees:  120       = 120
Minutes:  59 /60    = .98
Seconds : 89/3600   = 0.024722

Degrees + minutes + seconds = 121.004722
```

**FINAL LAT  = 14.513611**

**FINAL LONG = 121.004722**

expected location is

**Pascor Drive, Parañaque, Metro Manila, Philippines**

but it shows

**Chapel Road, Pasay, Metro Manila, Philippines**

I use this website to check if location is correct

http://www.doogal.co.uk/LatLong.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Degrees: 14           = 14
Minutes: 30.4903/60   = 0.5081717

Degrees + minutes + seconds = 14.50817

Degrees:  120         = 120
Minutes:  59.8999/60  = 0.9983317

Degrees + minutes + seconds = 120.9983317
```

(14.5081717,120.9983317)

Google's Geocoder tells me "Pascor Drive, Parañaque, Metro Manila, Philippines" is (14.507646,120.999653)

[Looks pretty close to me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Pascor%20Drive,%20Para%C3%B1aque,%20Metro%20Manila,%20Philippines&addr2=(14.5081717,120.9983317)&geocode=1&geocode=2)

Comment: Thanks. Question though....is this format (1430.4903) in degrees minutes only or does it have seconds....kinda confusing......

Comment: It is degrees and minutes.  No seconds, just fractional minutes.