# long lat format for someone in south east asia

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I was trying to convert something like lat long but it seems that I cannot get the exact location for this one.

LONG = 12035.1025    not yet converted

LAT  = 1427.2789     not yet converted

my first computation is like this

I just divided it to 1000.

```
LONG = 120.351025
LAT  = 14.272789
```

it game the wrong answer.

Second move I did was like this.

```
LONG = 120.351025
DEG  = 120
MIN  = .35 /60 = .005833
SEC  = 1025 / 3600 = .284722
LONGITUDE = 120.290555

LAT = 14.272789
DEG  = 14
MIN  = .27 /60 = .0045
SEC  = 2789 / 3600 = .774722
LONGITUDE = 14.779222
```

this however gave me a wrong location.

the location i was aiming for using the lat long above which is the

```
LONG = 12035.1025
LAT  = 1427.2789
```

is **Santa Cruz  Metro Manila** which is more or less closer to this LONG LAT but i have tried everything over the net to convert it. The closest LONG LAT im basing my conversion is

```
LONG = 120.983293   converted already
LAT  = 14.626308    converted already
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Convert Long Lat wrong location when displaying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337040/convert-long-lat-wrong-location-when-displaying), but that gives a location on the other side of the bay.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the official Geocoder API interface by Google by clicking on this [link](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html). Enter the address Santa Cruz Metro Manila and you will get Lat/Lng as :

Lat = 14.599
Lng = 120.9804

Comment: I was hoping to convert it by myself. I didn't know if what is the proper conversion formula to use for me to be able to get the right long lat.

Comment: That is good.. but why to do extra work when you already have tools to do this :)

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a tracker for myself so that I can budget gasoline.

Comment: I am not clear on the fact that the values you got intialy. May I know from where those Lat/Lng values came into play?

Comment: I have created a device which is connected to my cellphone(old android phone). then it throws data to my laptop. It throws a raw long lat in such format as I have given. I simply find it hard to find the proper conversion of this format.

Comment: But how can you be so sure that the device is throwing right coordinates but in some other format. May be its out of my knowledge but I have not seen such a format for coordinates. Usually its either decimal or degree min and sec!!